# getting the program arguments

Tags: haskell, module, program-entry-point

I need to get program arguments and show them

```
module Main ( main ) where

import System ( getArgs )

main = do

 args<-getArgs

 print $ show args
```

But it does nothing.Maybe my call incorrect?

```
>main 3 4
```

Comment: What's `main 3 4`? Is it how you invoke the compiled program from the command line?

Comment: $ ./test one two three
    "[\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"]"

works for me just fine.

Comment: I made this program then called it from ghc this way main 3 4.
but .hs name - number6+1.hs

Comment: @Артём Царионов: ghc 7.2, isn't it? :)

Comment: maybe you're not compiling it right.  What does `$ runhaskell main.hs one two three` do for you?

Comment: it's windows or linux?

ghc 7.04

Comment: By the way, `print $ show` is unnecessary. Look at the type of `print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing 'System' -> 'System.Environment':

```
module Main ( main ) where
import System.Environment ( getArgs )

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  mapM putStrLn args
```

Comment: `ghc --make Main` and `Main.exe arg1 arg2`

Comment: @Артём Царионов: guess you are calling `ghci` (interpreter), not `ghc` which is compiler... Run cmd, navigate to your source dir and execute `ghc --make Main`

Comment: @Артём Царионов: anyway, you'd better import `System.Environment` (afair, ghc switched to new import locations from 7.2 completely) http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=getargs

Comment: @Артём Царионов: in WinGhci you can compile with `:! ghc --make number6+2`

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to run the program from within GHCi. In that case, you can use the  `:main` command to run your program with arguments.

```
*Main> :main foo bar
"[\"foo\",\"bar\"]"
```